# GAS custom function error pulling data from another spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to pull data into a custom function in [spreadsheet1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0) from a [different spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_6pjeEdb0rbzj4mO2O74Tso4guSe2IboEaMozcnPwxA/edit#gid=168263988) and get the following error:

> You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required
> permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.

Looked this up and added the following:

1. *@NotOnlyCurrentDoc - In the function description area
2. Added "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"] into the appscript.json file
3. Enabled the Googles Sheets API, per documentation advising to the this

Still no luck. Even running the function from a custom menu and explicitly providing the required permission and the error persists.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) states that the spreadsheet service:

> Spreadsheet: Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).
> Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or
> SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()).

Is there a work around for this issue, apart from shoving all the data into a single spreadsheet?
While this is a personal project, I can see the same issue rearing itself with workplace spreadsheets and the "all in one spreadsheet" NOT being a viable solution.
Any help  would be great!

Custom function to be called:

```
    /**
*@customfunction
*@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function altWrktsTblSrch5(paramWrkout)
{
  //SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet & opendByUrl do NOT open the spreadsheet when it is a DIFFERENT spreadsheet being called BUT these 
  var dbSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit?pli=1#gid=45618254');
  
  //var sheet_alt_wrkts = dbSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Alt Workouts TABLE").getRange(2,1,100,6);
  var range_alt_wrkouts = sheet_alt_wrkts.getValues();
  var avlbl_non_sqntnl_alt_workts_array = range_alt_wrkouts.filter(e => e[3] && e[3] && e[4] == 'Yes' && e[5] == 'Non-sequential'); 
  var cols = [1, 3];
  var alt_wrkouts_array = avlbl_non_sqntnl_alt_workts_array.map(r => cols.map(i => r[i-1]));
  console.log(alt_wrkouts_array);
  var argWrkout = paramWrkout;

  //"Virtually" flattens the array without altering it and finds the ABSOLUTE index position of the desired element
  var index = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], alt_wrkouts_array))).indexOf(argWrkout); //'Walking' is passed in by the code in the function at the top
  console.log("Index: " +index );
  var numCols = alt_wrkouts_array[0].length;
  console.log("Number of columns: " +numCols);
  var rows = parseInt(index / numCols);
  console.log("Number of rows: " +rows);
  var cols = index % numCols;
  console.log(cols);
 

  //Test to confirm whether at the last row of the TYPE of alternative activity if NOT normal actions 
  if (alt_wrkouts_array[rows][cols-1] != alt_wrkouts_array[rows+1][cols-1])
  {
    index2 = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], alt_wrkouts_array))).indexOf(alt_wrkouts_array[rows][cols-1]);
    console.log("Index2: " +index2);
    numCols2 = alt_wrkouts_array[0].length;
    console.log("Number of columns2: " +numCols2);
    rows2 = parseInt(index2 / numCols2);
    console.log("Number of rows2: " +rows2);
    cols2 = index2 % numCols2;
    console.log(cols2);
    return console.log(alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2+1]); //returns to the first workout of the current alternate workout
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not open another spreadsheet from a custom function.  It simply isn't allowed.  You could do it through a menu option but you wouldn't be able to pass a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` cannot be used with the custom function, because of the current specification. But, about `Is there a work around for this issue, apart from shoving all the data into a single spreadsheet?`, in this case, as a workaround, how about using the following flow?

1. **Publicly share your Spreadsheet (`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit`) for retrieving the values.**
2. Retrieve the values from the Spreadsheet using UrlFetchApp as CSV data.

   - UrlFetchApp can be used with the custom function.
3. Parse the retrieved values as a 2-dimensional array of `range_alt_wrkouts`.

By this flow, the values can be retrieved from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit` with the custom function.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please confirm your Spreadsheet URL and ID again. Because your URL of `var dbSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit?pli=1#gid=45618254');` in your showing script is different from your provided Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

##### From:

```
var dbSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit?pli=1#gid=45618254');
var sheet_alt_wrkts = dbSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Alt Workouts TABLE").getRange(2, 1, 100, 6);
var range_alt_wrkouts = sheet_alt_wrkts.getValues();
```

##### To:

```
var id = "1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU";
var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=csv&id=${id}&range=${encodeURIComponent("A2:F101")}`;
var v = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var range_alt_wrkouts = Utilities.parseCsv(v);
```

- By modifying with the above workaround, when `=altWrktsTblSrch5("Walking")` is put into a cell using your provided Spreadsheets, `Mushin Meditation` is returned.

#### Note:

- In this case, your Spreadsheet of "Test - Alt Workouts Spreadsheet" is required to be publicly shared. When the Spreadsheet is not publicly shared, this modified script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.
- When your showing script is modified with the above workaround, it becomes as follows. In your script, `return console.log(alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2+1]);` is used. In this case, no value is returned. Please be careful about this. In this modification, I modified it to `return alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2+1];`.

```js
/**
*@customfunction
*@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function altWrktsTblSrch5(paramWrkout) {
  var id = "1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU";
  var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=csv&id=${id}&range=${encodeURIComponent("A2:F101")}`;
  var v = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var range_alt_wrkouts = Utilities.parseCsv(v);

  var avlbl_non_sqntnl_alt_workts_array = range_alt_wrkouts.filter(e => e[3] && e[3] && e[4] == 'Yes' && e[5] == 'Non-sequential');
  var cols = [1, 3];
  var alt_wrkouts_array = avlbl_non_sqntnl_alt_workts_array.map(r => cols.map(i => r[i - 1]));
  console.log(alt_wrkouts_array);
  var argWrkout = paramWrkout;

  var index = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], alt_wrkouts_array))).indexOf(argWrkout);
  console.log("Index: " + index);
  var numCols = alt_wrkouts_array[0].length;
  console.log("Number of columns: " + numCols);
  var rows = parseInt(index / numCols);
  console.log("Number of rows: " + rows);
  var cols = index % numCols;
  console.log(cols);

  if (alt_wrkouts_array[rows][cols - 1] != alt_wrkouts_array[rows + 1][cols - 1]) {
    index2 = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], alt_wrkouts_array))).indexOf(alt_wrkouts_array[rows][cols - 1]);
    console.log("Index2: " + index2);
    numCols2 = alt_wrkouts_array[0].length;
    console.log("Number of columns2: " + numCols2);
    rows2 = parseInt(index2 / numCols2);
    console.log("Number of rows2: " + rows2);
    cols2 = index2 % numCols2;
    console.log(cols2);

    console.log(alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2 + 1]);
    return alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2 + 1];
  }
  return null;
}
```

- If you cannot publicly shared your Spreadsheet, as the 2nd woaround, how about retrieving the values using `IMPORTRANGE`? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows. In this case, please put a function of `=altWrktsTblSrch5(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit","'Alt Workouts TABLE'!A2:F101"),"Walking")` into a cell. By this, the values are retrieved without publicly shared the Spreadsheet. In this case, before you put the function, please put `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6_NGs3YFKPyBuNA-5xVzlJRL8aB0zFwb-EOunyVzqU/edit","'Alt Workouts TABLE'!A2:F101")` into a cell and authorize it. By this, the above custom function can be used.

```js
/**
*@customfunction
*@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function altWrktsTblSrch5(range_alt_wrkouts, paramWrkout) {
  var avlbl_non_sqntnl_alt_workts_array = range_alt_wrkouts.filter(e => e[3] && e[3] && e[4] == 'Yes' && e[5] == 'Non-sequential');
  var cols = [1, 3];
  var alt_wrkouts_array = avlbl_non_sqntnl_alt_workts_array.map(r => cols.map(i => r[i - 1]));
  console.log(alt_wrkouts_array);
  var argWrkout = paramWrkout;

  var index = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], alt_wrkouts_array))).indexOf(argWrkout);
  console.log("Index: " + index);
  var numCols = alt_wrkouts_array[0].length;
  console.log("Number of columns: " + numCols);
  var rows = parseInt(index / numCols);
  console.log("Number of rows: " + rows);
  var cols = index % numCols;
  console.log(cols);

  if (alt_wrkouts_array[rows][cols - 1] != alt_wrkouts_array[rows + 1][cols - 1]) {
    index2 = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], alt_wrkouts_array))).indexOf(alt_wrkouts_array[rows][cols - 1]);
    console.log("Index2: " + index2);
    numCols2 = alt_wrkouts_array[0].length;
    console.log("Number of columns2: " + numCols2);
    rows2 = parseInt(index2 / numCols2);
    console.log("Number of rows2: " + rows2);
    cols2 = index2 % numCols2;
    console.log(cols2);

    console.log(alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2 + 1]);
    return alt_wrkouts_array[rows2][cols2 + 1];
  }
  return null;
}
```

- By the way, in your question, you say `Added "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"] into the appscript.json file`. In this case, when you directly run the function, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` is also required to be used. So, please be careful about this.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for taking the time to really breakdown the issue and for bringing the error to my attention with my putting in the incorrect URL for the getURL method.  Cheers!!!